# Optimizing Mysql Query

Tags: php, sql, mysql, optimization

What is the general "best practice" for this type of functionality.

I have a table of users a table of polls and a table of poll responses on a website. I want to load a page that loads a poll that a user hasn't yet answer.

What is the most efficient and "best" way of going about this.

Things I've tried that seems slow/not optimal:

A query with nested selects using NOT IN

```
SELECT p.id
FROM poll p
WHERE p.id NOT IN (
    SELECT r.pollID
    FROM responses r
    WHERE r.username = 'someuser'
)
```

A query that uses left joins

```
LEFT JOIN  responses ON ( polls.id = responses.pollID
AND responses.username =  'someuser' ) 
WHERE
responses.username IS NULL
```

Both of these solutions seem to scale very poorly.

Other suggestions? Open to anything outside the box. (I.E. solutions that aren't confined to just different types of mysql queries)

Comment: do you have proper indexes on your tables?

Comment: Use the EXPLAIN command before your query to see how MySQL breaks down the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both these queries are of same efficiency as long as you have a composite index on `responses (pollID, username)`

If your queries are slow, this most probably means you don't have this index.

`LEFT JOIN` combined with `IS NULL` on a non-`NULL` column is optimized by `MySQL` so that it returns a row as soon as it sees there is no matching value in the right column.

You can see it in the `EXPLAIN` as `Not exists` in the `Extra` column.

`NOT IN` is optimized in the same way too, you can see it as `<not exists>` in the warning message provided by the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED`.

See this entry in my blog for more details:

- [**NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL**](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

The left join should work great if you give `responses` a compound key on `pollID` and `username`.

Though it's somewhat distressing that you're using a username as a key, as opposed to a numeric user ID.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the consequences of using the username as a key? Sorry, I lack understanding at some of this.

Comment: Wastes storage, makes operations using it a tiny bit slower, maybe (if it's a variable-width column) makes the table variable-width instead of fixed-width, which also makes things slower.  And it's just kind of messy.

Answer (score 0):

Solution #1:

How does a straight up left join perform for you?

```
LEFT JOIN  responses ON ( polls.id = responses.pollID
AND responses.username =  'someuser' )
```

If it performs OK, you can simply retrieve a full list of polls like this and then filter out the rows where username is not null in the caller code.

Solution #2:

Make sure your indices are OK. You should have ann index in username (or poll ID+username) in responses.

Answer (score -1):

I think a Left Join is going to be your best bet here. however, I am confused as to why in your example you check the username, then in the where clause, see if it's null. it should look like this:

```
LEFT JOIN  responses ON ( polls.id = responses.pollID) 
WHERE
responses.username = 'someuser'
```

Comment: Won't this start to be a burden when users have answered thousands of polls? Also, I'm trying to find a poll that the user has not answered yet. Would your solution find polls that they have answered?

Comment: Because he wants to avoid retrieving rows where poll is already answered. Unless that is specifically what causes the slowness (see my answer) it's actually a perfectly fine thing to do.